# Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ with scalar multiplication only applying to the first element a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, solution-verification

I am trying to determine which axioms of a vector space do not hold for the following:

Let $V$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$, but with scalar multiplication defined as:

$a(x_1, y_1) = (ax_1, y_1)$

I can't find which axiom fails.

However, I don't think this is a vector space as I know, if $V$, with $u \in V$ is a vector space then $(-1)u = -u$, but this is not true for $V$.

What have I missed?

Comment: In a vector space $0 \cdot \mathbf{v}=\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: @Gary Do you know which axioms of a vector space cause this to be untrue for $V$ in this example?

Comment: Go through the axioms one by one.  If you can't see how they could fail, try to prove them.  Are there any you can't prove?

Comment: The distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition does not hold: $(2x,y) = 2(x,y) = (1 + 1)(x,y) = 1(x,y) + 1(x,y) =(x,y) + (x,y)= (x + x,y + y) = (2x,2y)$. This is not true unless $y=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Gary's comment. Excellent way to show that under this product $\mathbb R^2$ is not a vector space.

Here is an alternative way, I am assuming that the **sum** of two vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ is defined as usual sense i.e. $(x,y)+(u,v)=(x+u,y+v)$, and the scalar product is defined as $c(x,y)=(cx,y)$. Then the following contradiction occurs, $$(1,1)+(1,1)=(2,2)\ne (2,1)=2\times(1,1).$$